# What value can a Rails route helper have as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails tutorial and I don't understand the value a route helper can have as parameter.

Why is it correct for the "article_path" to have "article" as its parameter?

```
<ul id=“articles”>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because you are passing the whole object as a parameters when parameters comes to controller, controller get id form parameter and give a particular record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
article_path(article)
```

**Is valid** Because you are passing the whole object as a parameter when parameters come to the controller, controller get the id from parameter and give a particular record.

I suggest you follow the standard way using `article_path(article.id)` because if you have number of fields in article model (table) then all filed are pass in the parameter.

Comment: So you recommend using (article.id) as the parameter...in that case, what should the value be between the pipes? It seems like the parameter being article.id and the value between the pipes to be article works.

Comment: pipes? when you pass like this `article_path(article.id)` than params only have id, not extra value.

Comment: I am referring to the value within |article| in the line <% @articles.each do |article| %>. Should it be |article.id| ? Or should it stay as |article| ?

Comment: you should do like this `<% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article.id) %>
        </li>
    <% end %>`

Answer (score 1):

In below route:

```
article_path(article)
```

you can pass `article` as whole object or `article.id` both are valid.

Comment: Is article preferred over article.id? The latter seems more intuitive to me but was wondering which one is the more conventional way.

In the case of article.id, does the object between the pipes have to be article.id as well?

Comment: @Robert you can pass anything but `article` is best because you pass whole object and controller fetch id from object.